# Need to iterate over entire object except for first two elements. Is there a design pattern?

Tags: c++, loops, design-patterns, foreach

I have a `std::vector` that I would like to iterate over each object except the first two. A foreach loop would be perfect if I didn't want two . i.e. `for(const auto i : items)`

Possible solutions I've thought of are erasing the first two and re-adding at the end

```
const auto firstEle = myVec[0];
const auto secEle = myVec[1];
myVec.erase(myVec.begin());
myVec.erase(myVec.begin());
for(const auto i : items)
{
  //do stuff with i
}
myVec.insert(myVec.begin(), secEle);
myVec.insert(myVec.begin(), firstEle);
```

or have some sort of flag

```
unsigned int i = 0;
for(const auto j : items)
{
  if(i < 2)
  {
    i++;
    continue;
   }
   //do stuff with j
}
```

or use a while loop

```
unsigned int i = 2;
while(i < myVec.size())
{
  const auto j = myVec[i];
  //do stuff with j

  i++;
}
```

All these seem more complicated than they need to be. Any better solutions that are simpler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually go with a conventional loop for these things:

```
// verify myVec.size() > 2
for(auto it = myVec.begin()+2; it != myVec.end(); ++it) {
    // work
}
```

If you want C++11 lambda magic, then

```
std::for_each(v.begin()+2, v.end(), [](auto& element) {
     // do stuff
});
```

will do it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use std::advance to skip the first 2 elements, but whether you do that or not, I'd still recommend the approach in this answer in preference to those in the question.

Comment: Isn't `it` an iterator so it still needs to be dereferenced? If so, how's it better than my 3 suggestion? :)

Comment: This may appear to work, but it risks UB: If `myVec.size() == 1`, `myVec.begin()+2` will increment the iterator beyond `myVec.end()`, and pink elephants may appear. This will strike even when the iterators are just pointers because `it` will never compare equal to `myVec.end()` (because it will be larger from the off).

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I guess you did not read that first comment that thoroughly.

Comment: @northerner I don't understand your comment. There is no "better" here, you asked for common practices. These are practices I see often enough. Yours are fine too.

Comment: @kabanu Which "first comment"?

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica "// verify myVec.size() > 2" -> first thing in answer code.

Comment: @northerner Now that I think about it, the insertion may be slow, so I would not recommend the first approach.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm blind.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica No worries, the warning is valid and important.

Comment: Nevertheless, had I seen the comment, I would not have downvoted. Unfortunately, I cannot retract my downvote anymore unless you make some edit to your answer.

Comment: @kabanus "the insertion may be slow" what insertion?

Comment: @northerner `myVec.insert(myVec.begin(), firstEle);` -> your first example. I wasn't clear - I meant the first of your examples.

Answer (score 3):

In C++20, you can use [`std::views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view). Taken directly from the example at [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com):

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    for (int i : nums | std::views::drop(2))
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to approach this kind of problems is to simply fall back to an indexed loop:

```
for(int i = 2; i < myVec.size(); i++) {
    //do stuff with `myVec[i]`
}
```

For `std::vector<>`, this is just as efficient as the iterator based loop, and the loop control says exactly what it does on the lid. Most importantly, because you are comparing integers for `<` instead of iterators for `!=`, you do not run any risk to trigger undefined behavior when the vector is too short.

Comment: I access the contents of each elements several time in a loop. So I would do `const auto ele = myVec[i]`, right? Aside from efficiency, I find it easier to read without `[ ]`.

Comment: @northerner Well, I would use a reference instead of a value, i.e. `const auto& element = ...` or `auto& element = ...` if changes are necessary. And yes, that's a typical way to avoid repetition of the `[i]`. What is more readable depends on the circumstances, though.